# How to claim ethernet - Network showing as unclaimed

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

Ethernet and WiFi are being shown as unclaimed while running

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0010000-f001ffff

$ sudo dhclient -v eno1
Cannot find device "eno1"
Error getting hardware address for "eno1": No such device
```

and no `network-Manager`, only CLI.

```
$ uname -a
Linux gumby-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:1984]

$ apt-cache policy linux-firmware{,-nonfree}?
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 1.169.3
  Candidate: 1.169.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.169.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.169.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages
     1.169 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages
linux-firmware-snapdragon:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
N: Unable to locate package linux-firmware-nonfree?
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-firmware-nonfree?'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-firmware-nonfree?'
```

sudo modprobe r8169 [sudo] password for gumby: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'option' modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic

dmesg | grep -wFe r8169 --no output

Comment: How to claim Ethernet to get back on network?

Comment: redid question thank you for your help. I'm just going to due a clean install.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a`, `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'` and `apt-cache policy linux-firmware{,-nonfree}`? Thanks.

Comment: edited with added items

Comment: Alright. Could you please add the output of `sudo modprobe r8169; dmesg | grep -wFe r8169`? Thanks.